# how to select the chosen object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multilingual

This is my JavaScript object:

```
   {
    "login" : {
        "title" : "title1"
        "content1" : "content1"
        }
    "Menu" : {
        "title" : "title2"  
        }
    }
```

How do I get the value of of a property of the JavaScript object with function `getvalue("login","title")` or `getvalue("login","content1")` and return `title1` or `content1`? I do this to make a multi-language phonegap apps so when the function called i compare with `lang` attribute in html, i use xui and pure javascript and no jquery becouse it's to heavy for phonegap i think.. can anyone help me? or is there any best method for multilanguage?

Comment: I want the flexible way. the function have param that can also change into getValue("menu", "title") this only sample json. the real json can be much more, can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming this is a standard json in a standard variable: var myJson. Why cant you return

`myJson.login.title` (per this syntax)

In the example above login is not an array so you wouldnt be able to return a list of login values

With regards to internationalization I would do something simpler (and I have been doing that successfully in my apps). Just create a set of name-value pairs in a file calls language.en.xml (or json etc depending if you can easily parse json or xml using your framework) and one called language.it.xml if lets say you wanted to have the italian language as well. Then each key (e.g. login) is the same for every file and the value is the title you want to have in each language. So pretty similar to yours but you dont need a hierarchy.

Then you can create a static method called Internationalize('Login') that will return the value of login for the language the user has chosen. So in your method you will check the users language settings and read the value from the required file. If language is IT then check value in language.it.xml (or json etc.) if default or NULL or en then check the english file.

Optimizations like pre-loading the language file contents in memory are also things you should be thinking about.

Comment: I know the purpose i create file language.en.json but i dont know how to change that value maybe from it.json to the html so i create function  getvalue("login","title") to return the value that i called in html.. is this way wrong?

Comment: Is getValue using AJAX to get the value? or is it a normal function that does the work synchronously? If its asynchronous expect delays in loading the full page with the text. I dont know what you are using to generate your HTML pages (if in fact you do have a backend app) but if you dont thats kind of your only choice.

Comment: i make it using AJAX but i save the json file in client not in server. I think i will make it fast and it synchronously. right now i generate with brower but i closed the security issue with AJAX so i can get the json value

Comment: There are problems with this approach. First things first if it is in fact an AJAX call then by definition its not synchronous (AJAX is Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). Therefore the effect will be that you load your page, you create a bunch of AJAX requests to translate the labels to the users language and he waits a few milliseconds / seconds etc. for the labels to render. Meanwhile, depending on your implementation, he sees no labels or he sees labels for the default language. This is something that you generally want to do server-side.

Comment: okay than, if i use your recommend without the hierarchy, how can i implement into the HTML? is there any javascript library you use?

Comment: But I have a backend as well and render things per my original post. I would suggest to read a few things on javascript, jquery and json manipulation to get things going.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON

```
myJSON = { 
  'login' : { 'title' : 'title1'},
  'menu' : { 'title' : 'title2'} 
};
```

You can call the value like this:

```
alert(myJSON.login.title);
```

it will output: title1.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer finally, here it is :

```
var data = {
"login" : {
    "title" : "title1"
    "content1" : "content1"
    }
"Menu" : {
    "title" : "title2"  
    }
}

function getvalue(resource, paramA, ParamB) 
{
   return resource[paramA][paramB];
}
```

end then just called :

```
getvalue(data,"login","content1")
```

it will return `content1`

huff, finally i found this :)